# How to calculate time difference (in second) in excel vba for different group of unique values?

Tags: vba, excel

I know this question appears often previously, but what I have is in the different case. I have some data about date and time which is for two groups. I want to know the duration for each group, but I dont know how to write it in the Excel VBA codes. Could you please help me to solve it?
Here is my excel sheet. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjhv7.png)
The hard thing is that when in the same group it has changed to other date but when I try to substract the difference, it can be minus not positive. for example :

```
02.09.2017 19:00:00
03.09.2017 01:00:00
```

In this case I can't substract 01:00:00 - 19:00:00 because that would be minus, thus I have to consider the change of the date. How can I solve it if it is the case? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: In what format is duration required? hh:mm:ss ?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to tell. It is in second (s) @QHarr

Comment: First of all, you need to be familiar with how computers handle time values. It's measured in seconds (or milliseconds) from a starting date. When you write 02.09.2017 19:00:00, it's just a human representation of the count of seconds from the start date. Thus you can subtract (or add) any date to any other since it's just a huge number (of seconds or milliseconds, you do not need to know that part) to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If your cells are formatted as data and time, you can use `DateDiff` function, with `"n"` as the interval (represnting the dif in seconds).

I've tested with your data:

```
A1 02.09.2017 19:00:00 
A2 03.09.2017 01:00:00
```

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalcSecond()

Dim NumofSec As Long

NumofSec = DateDiff("n", Range("A1").Value, Range("A2").Value)

MsgBox NumofSec

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not answering the exact question i think. The OP will need to find the first and last match for each event in the range and then perform a difference on the associated datetimes. They may need to perform some form of concatenation as they are not in the same field, conversions as 02.09.2017 is seen as a string etc , then they can do a datediff.

Comment: They also need a concept of creating and working with a range.